# Unable to Rewrite URL with IIS7 Url Rewrite

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am having an issue with the Url Rewrite module in IIS7. I have read several posts about this type of issue and I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the rule:

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 11" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="/s\/([\w\%20\s]+)\/default\.aspx" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="\/landingpage.aspx\?mc={R:1}" 
     logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

I imported it from a previous ISAPI ini filter that looks like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^\/s\/([\w\-\_\%20\s]+)\/default\.aspx \/landingpage.aspx\?mc=$1 [L,I]
```

I had to tweak the regular expression a bit to get it to work with the built in tester but it is matches against urls like

```
/s/RETQ211CA/default.aspx
```

And according to the log the request is coming through as:

```
2012-10-18 15:41:54 ::1 GET /s/RETQ211CA/default.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 404 0 0 1468
```

This happens locally or through the internet.

Can someone tell me what exactly I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following rule will do the trick:

```
s\/([\w\%20\s]+)\/default\.aspx
```

You could start this rule with ^ and terminate with $ if you'd like.

The confusion is that url rewrite assumes you're in the root.